# How to set space between the axis and the label

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

**My code:**

```
#importing required libraries
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


#plotting data

def func(x):
    return (x-3)*(x+2)*(3*x+5)+25
a,b=2,9
x=np.linspace(0,10,30)
y=func(x)
fig,ax=plt.subplots(1,1,dpi=135)
ax.plot(x,y,linewidth=2.5,color='c')
ix=np.linspace(a,b)
iy=func(ix)
verts=[(a,0),*zip(ix,iy),(b,0)]
poly=Polygon(verts,facecolor='0.7',edgecolor='0.9')
ax.add_patch(poly)
ax.set_ylim(bottom=0)
ax.text(6.5,150,r'$\int_a^b f(x)$',horizontalalignment='center',fontsize=15)
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y',rotation=0)
ax.set_xticks((a,b))
ax.set_xticklabels(('a','b'))
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.set_yticks([])
plt.show()
```

The above code gives:

[image]

**My Question:**

So as you have saw the above plot the ylabel 'Y' is touching with the y-axis and there is space between the xlabel 'X' and x-axis

*How can I set space between the axis and the label(like there is a space between xlabel and x-axis)?*

**My attempt:**

In the above code I commented `set_ylabel()` method and tried `text()` method

```
#ax.set_ylabel('Y',rotation=0)
fig.text(0.1,0.5,'Y')
#this code creating a little space between y label and y-axis but I want the same amount of space that is between x label an x axis
```

**Expected output:**

[image]

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can set bounding by using labelpad argument like this

```
ax.set_ylabel('Y', rotation=0, labelpad=10)
```

also you can add space after 'Y ' label in set_ylabel line as following

```
ax.set_ylabel('Y ',rotation=0)
```

**Note:**

As you mentioned you want the same spaces between both axis labels so you can set **'X'** label using:

```
 ax.text(max(x)/2, -(max(y)/10),'X')
```

**and**

**'Y'** label using:

```
 ax.text(-(max(x)/10), max(y)/2,'Y')
```

Comment: As you mentioned you want the same spaces between both axis labels so yo can set 'X' lable using  ```ax.text(max(x)/2, -(max(y)/10),'X')``` and 'Y' label using 
```ax.text(-(max(x)/10), max(y)/2,'Y')```

Comment: I was just missing the `labelpad` parameter in `set_ylabel()` method....Since you answered First....so I am accepting this as an answer...Thanks again **:)**

Comment: And you can set that with `fig.text(0.1,0.5,'Y')` But here X axis is ranges from 0 to 10 and Y axis from 0 to approx. 3000. So you need to set both values 0.1 and 0.5 respectively to the scale of X and Y axis.

Answer (score 5):

If you adjust the horizontal position of the label, you will have the same space as usual.

```
ax.set_ylabel('Y', rotation=0, ha='right')
```

If you need more space, you can use the following settings.

```
ax.yaxis.labelpad = 20
```

Comment: This method is alternate to `fig.text(0.1,0.5,'Y')`...As I mentioned in the question that I want the same amount of space that is between x label an x axis....btw thank for answering **:)**